# How do I install mupen64plus on lubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

How do I install mupen64plus on Lubuntu? I can't find it on the Lubuntu Software Center. It is a tar.gz file.

Answer (score 0):

first download the tar specific for Ubuntu. Open terminal and type

```
wget https://mupen64plus.googlecode.com/files/mupen64plus-bundle-linux32-2.0.tar.gz
```

then untar the file

```
tar xvf mupen64plus-bundle-linux32-2.0.tar.gz
```

go inside the directory and run the installation

```
cd mupen64plus-bundle-linux32-2.0.tar.gz
./install.sh
```

et voilà!

Comment: Note that OP mentioned Lubuntu, so it's likely he's using 32 bit system.